# ASP.NET Vertically wrapping a list generated by a repeater

Tags: asp.net, css, list, xhtml, repeater

I've got my repeater generating a list of links that need to appear in a certain order. Meaning I need my list to appear like so

```
-Item1 -Item4
-Item2 -Item5
-Item3
```

Every solution I've found involves knowing whats going to be in your list and setting classes where the list should break. My issue is that it could be anywhere from 1 to 18 items.

So my question is, is there a good, simple way to vertically wrap a list that's being dynamically generated using an ASP.NET repeater control?

Comment: It seems likely that an answer to this would involve HTML and CSS.  You may want to consider adding those tags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an idea.  This assumes that the number of items to display vertically before wrapping is a fixed number, or at least a number that can be determined by the server (see the VerticalWrapLimit constant).  I.e. it is not related to the height of the users's browser.

```
<script runat="server">
    void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        rptVerticalWrap.DataSource = new[] {
            new { ID = 1, Name = "ABC" },
            new { ID = 2, Name = "BCD" },
            new { ID = 3, Name = "CDE" },
            new { ID = 4, Name = "DEF" },
            new { ID = 5, Name = "EFG" },
            new { ID = 6, Name = "FGH" },
            new { ID = 7, Name = "GHI" },
            new { ID = 8, Name = "HIJ" },
        };
        rptVerticalWrap.DataBind(); 
    }

    int count;
    const int VerticalWrapLimit = 5;
</script>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    <% count = 0; %>
    <div style="float:left;">
            <asp:Repeater ID="rptVerticalWrap" runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%
                        if (count % VerticalWrapLimit == 0 && count > 0)
                        {
                            %></div><div style="float:left;"><%                     
                        }
                        count++;
                    %>
                    <div>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" Text="ID: " /><asp:TextBox runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
                        <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Name: " /><asp:TextBox runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' />
                    </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
    </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

For this sort of problem, I think what you need to do is identify what you want the resulting HTML to look like first, then write the ASP code to generate that.

In this case, I wrapped each vertical column of data in a  with style="float:left;".  I used a class scoped "count" variable in order to identify when I needed to close off the current div and start a new one.  The count variable has to be a class-level variable because the contents of the Repeater's ItemTemplate has a different scope than the rest of the page.

Comment: Ill try to implement this tonight, and if I have any luck I'll mark this as the answer. Thanks.

Comment: This would work in the situation you described - but I ended up wrapping the list items horizontally with fixed widths so they appear to be in two columns. It was too difficult to determine how big the list would be because it wasn't a fixed number of items each time.

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully achieved by using div tags with style as shown in the code below:

```html
<asp:Repeater ID="rptAnswers" runat="server">
 <ItemTemplate>
  <div style="width:100%;display:table-row;">
   <div style="display: table-cell; padding: 5px; margin-left: 25px">
    <asp:Label ID="lblOrdPos" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Predictable" Text='<%# Eval("ansLetter")%>'></asp:Label>)
   </div>
   <div style="display: table-cell; padding: 5px;" class="ansCtrl">
    <asp:RadioButton ID="gvrbAns" ClientIDMode="Predictable" CssClass="gvrbAnswers" GroupName="gvrbAnswers" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("ansVal") = 1 %>' />
    <asp:CheckBox ID="gvchkAns" ClientIDMode="Predictable" CssClass="gvchkAnswer" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("ansVal") = 1 %>' />
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblAnswer" ClientIDMode="Predictable" CssClass="ansTrueFalse" runat="server">
     <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="True"></asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="False"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
   </div>
   <div style="display: table-cell; padding: 5px;">
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblAnswerTxt" ClientIDMode="Predictable" Text='<%# Eval("txt") %>'></asp:Label>
   </div>
  </div>
  
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```